# Error code while compiling a project: Undefined symbol for architecture arm64

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to compile a projet with a makefile but I get this error message :

```
g++   testVecteur2D.o Vecteur2D.o   -o testVecteur2D
```

> ld: warning: ignoring file Vecteur2D.o, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64

> ld: warning: ignoring file testVecteur2D.o, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "_main", referenced from:
> implicit entry/start for main executable
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make: *** [testVecteur2D] Error 1

my code is working on other computer so I don't understand why it is not on mine. For information I'm using de new m1 Mac maybe it has something to do with it.

Comment: It means neither of those object code files has a `main`, which is mandatory for a proper runnable executable program. You're getting it from *somewhere* on your other rig. Check it again, and/or check your source and determine why it is missing.

Comment: ... and perhaps your object files are old (from when you built for x86_64)? Try removing all object files and rebuild. If the `Makefile` has a `clean` target, use that. `make clean` then `make testVecteur2D`.

Comment: the thing is that I do I have a main that is why I don't understand why I received this error message

Comment: Your object files are built for a different architecture than you're linking for (note that `ld` explicitly says that it's ignoring them for this reason). Were the object files created on your other computer?

Comment: The warnings you get indicate that the object files weren't built on your system, but somewhere else and then copied onto your system. That's generally not a good idea. If you have access to the source files used to create those object files, then build them on your current system instead.

Comment: I'm doing a project with another person and he built the files. So I just have to delete the executable and recreate them using the same code ?

Comment: Not only the executable - all object files. Since you run on different architectures, it's better if you only share the source code - no binary files.

Comment: @ml64 Great! You're welcome!